# How to change the value of an element nested inside two iframes through chrome console?

Tags: html, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, dom, google-chrome-console

I have an element that is in an iframe and that iframe is in another iframe, so they're nested. I want to change the value of it, but I can't do that since I don't think chrome console can find it.

```
document.querySelector('#someRandomCssSelector').value = "newValue"
```

Is there a way to specify the two iframes the element is nested in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Incase the element is within an [***iframe***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447):

[image: element_iframe]

Then if you shift your focus to the *Console* tab you will find a dropdown with the first item being called ***top*** containing the desired frame as a child as follows:

[image: console_iframe]

Like wise select the desired iframe in the *Console* tab in which the desired element is located.

Next, given the HTML:

```
<input id="accountName" autocomplete="email" autofocus="" class="form-textbox-input fin-input__input" data-test="accountName-input" dir="auto" name="accountName" required="" type="text">
```

To populate the `<input>` field with the text ***newValue*** you can execute the following command in the *Console*:

```
document.querySelector('input#accountName').value = "newValue"
```

Console snapshot:

[image: newValue]